# How to pass variables in PHP with form action like solution to another PHP file after POST evaluation?

Tags: php

I have a form (user fills a textform, also upload a file), I am evaluating / validating the inputs. But after that how can I pass the post variablas as POST paramaters (like when a form used with submit button), to another PHP file ?

My sample code is:

```
echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<textarea name="identity" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>';
echo "<input type='file' name='uploaded_file'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='upload_file_test' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["identity"])) {
     $error_identity = "Empty identity, type something in the fields";
     $correct_inputs=false;
   } else {
     $correct_inputs=true;
   }
}


if($correct_inputs === TRUE){

    pass $_POST["identity"], $_POST["file"] (including temp name, and other data) to index2.php

}
```

So how can I achive it like with something like form action to pass these to index2.php after $correct_inputs is TRUE ?

Comment: `$_POST["file"]` that's a file and not text. So, `$_FILES["uploaded_file"]` (edit) as per @Dagon 's catch and also using the wrong array name - RTM on it http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- and i thought it was `$_FILES["uploaded_file"]`

Comment: @Dagon good catch, I edited mine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i should of waited for 5 minutes to expire :-)

Comment: @Dagon Oh sure and make me look like a monkey's uncle. Cousin maybe... uncle... *hm...*. Then I'd have to buy them all swings of their own.

Comment: Fred -ii- and Dragon: thank you for the feedback, will fix it in my sample code. Have you got any idea how to pass the POST variables after POST to another php file, based on my code ?

Comment: You're welcome, but I don't know why you're trying to post to the same file then wanting to pass that information to another. What I'd do is just use a standard HTML form, then on the second page  and using `action="otherfile.php"`, process what's been set/not empty. If you want to use the way you have now, you'll need to use Ajax. The link I gave you above for files, shows you how to process files. To process the PHP inputs, you'd do `$var=$_POST['var'];` and checking for `empty()`'ness. To process from the same and passing it to another, you could probably get away with sessions.

Comment: Fred -ii- : first I want to validate the POST inputs in index1.php (is identity empty or not, if file has been selected, file is not too large, etc). If the validation is okay, then I want to call index2.php to use the post parameters from index1.php

Comment: you'll need to use Ajax for this then.

Comment: Fred -ii-: thank you. I am not familiar with Ajax, so I skip this function in my application.